# Generate random number, between 2 numbers?

Tags: javascript, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating random numbers in Javascript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Say I wanted to generate a random number from 50 to 100.

I know there's:

```
Math.random()
```

but I could only find ways to go from 1 to 'x'

Comment: Do you know how to translate an integer interval?

Comment: If you know how to go from 1 to x why not just make x = 51 and add 49?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range

Answer (score 12):

From [MDN on `Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

```
// Returns a random integer between min and max
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would also work:

```
function randomInt(min,range) {
return Math.floor((Math.random()*(range+1))+min)
}
```

In your case min would be 50 and range would be 50

Comment: Due to the `Math.floor()` and the random interval `[0,1)` this can never yield `100` so you need `(Math.random()*(min+1))`. Also this formula only is working because `min == range` here, they need to be switched.

Comment: Dammit :/ can't have been very awake last night! :P

Comment: well, happens to the best of us^^